# Import non-integer constant in .pyx file

Tags: cython

How can I declare constants (of various types - not just enum values) and share them between multiple `.pyx` files?

Within a `.pyx` file, I can declare and use constants:

```
DEF FavouriteFood = "spam"
DEF ArraySize = 42
print(FavouriteFood)
print(ArraySize)
```

And using a `.pxd` file, I can [share C functions](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-c-functions) or [share types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types).

But how can I share constants? The docs indicate a [very limited way of doing this with anonymous enums](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#c-variable-and-type-definitions), but values in those can only be ints. How can I import, for example, a constant string or float into a `.pyx` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a very short inline function ([in the pxd file](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html)) that just returns the constant

```
cdef inline const char* GetFavouriteFood():
    return "spam"

cdef inline float GetHowMuch():
    return 4.5
```

The other option would be to define the constants in C in a header file then (in your pxd) do

```
cdef extern from "myconstants.h":
   const char* FavouriteFood
   float HowMuch
```

The C compiler (rather than Cython) enforces the constness so errors will appear at that stage if you try to change them. This does involve create an extra file so personally I prefer the inline function approach.

---

Edit (2018):

You can now include C code directly in Cython which makes the second approach easier:

```
cdef extern from *:
   """const char* FavouriteFood = "spam";
   const float HowMuch = 4.5;"""
   const char* FavouriteFood
   float HowMuch
```