# Referencing Cython constants in Python

Tags: cython, cythonize

I have a C-header file (let's call it myheader.h) that contains some character string definitions such as:

```
#define MYSTRING "mystring-constant"
```

In Cython, I create a cmy.pxd file that contains:

```
cdef extern from "myheader.h":
    cdef const char* MYSTRING "MYSTRING"
```

and a corresponding my.pyx file that contains some class definitions, all headed by:

```
from cmy cimport *
```

I then try to reference that string in a Python script:

```
from my import *

def main():
     print("CONSTANT ", MYSTRING)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Problem is that I keep getting an error:

```
NameError: name 'MYSTRING' is not defined
```

I've searched the documentation and can't identify the problem. Any suggestions would be welcomed - I confess it is likely something truly silly.

Comment: For functions you to have use something like `cpdef` to make them visible from Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import non-integer constant in .pyx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624179/import-non-integer-constant-in-pyx-file)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766219/export-constants-from-header-with-cython) is also related but not quite what you're after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access cdef-variables from Python. So you have to create a Python object which would correspond to your define, something like this (it uses Cython>=0.28-feature [verbatim-C-code](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code), so you need a recent Cython version to run the snippet):

```
%%cython
cdef extern from *:   
    """
    #define MYSTRING "mystring-constant"
    """
    # avoid name clash with Python-variable
    # in cdef-code the value can be accessed as MYSTRING_DEFINE
    cdef const char* MYSTRING_DEFINE "MYSTRING"

#python variable, can be accessed from Python
#the data is copied from MYSTRING_DEFINE   
MYSTRING = MYSTRING_DEFINE
```

and now `MYSTRING` is a bytes-object:

```
>>> print(MYSTRING)
b'mystring-constant'
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks! I wonder if there is a way to reference a variable with the *same* name in the cdef-code and in the python code? That would be usefull for debugging cythonized .py code.