# Not allowed in a constant expression for module access

Tags: cython, cythonize

I have two cython files:

**intern.pxd**

```
cdef int test = 8
```

**extern.pyx**

```
cimport intern

cpdef enum test_enum:
    test = intern.test
```

If I try to compile this, It throws the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport intern

cpdef enum test_enum:
    test = intern.test                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

side_tests\extern.pyx:4:17: Not allowed in a constant expression
```

I guess this is because the value of `intern.test` can not be known at compile time. I would like to get a solution for this. It is not an option to export the values of `intern.pxd` into `extern.pyx` because in the real project `intern.pxd` contains around 2000 external defined values/functions.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624179/import-non-integer-constant-in-pyx-file/36629079#36629079 ? Is either the "make the constants an `enum`" solution suggested in the question or the "wrap the constants in an inline function" solution in my answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes, the 'wrap in enum' works, but still feels a bit weird. (Why can't I use the directly?) By the way, the real ones are define in a c header file, so I do not understand what you mean in your answer. You say that would solve it, but it does do it.

Comment: You're right - when I test using a value from a C header in that context it doesn't work, so my answer to that question isn't useful for you.

Comment: Do you want to add an answer, or should I do an self answer? (It is not a duplicate)

Comment: I agree it's not a duplicate (the need to work with Cython enums definitely makes a difference). I don't really want to add an answer because I don't really have a good solution. You're welcome to do a self-answer for wrap in enum, but hopefully someone might have a better idea

Answer (score 0):

@DavidW pointed me to the working solution 'wrap in enum':

```
# In intern.pxd
cdef enum test_enum_intern: 
    test = 8
```

This works, but feels 'weird'. If somebody has another solution, he is welcome to post it.